# Automated GUI testing for virtual reality apps

Tags: automated-testing, vr

So im working with a team on Oculus Rift and gear VR apps and I started looking into testing automation. I was wondering if anyone else started looking into testing automation for VR apps. Specifically GUI since I think that will be the main problem considering the input devices.

We use Unity alongside Oculus sdk so far and we have looked into automating performance testing. Unity's profiler is a nice tool to check performance. We have some of our own checks in place. We need to automate them and much more.

Answer (score 1):

Automating software related functionality you can easily automate.

I guess, blocker will come when you want to take inputs from actual wearable. That can be resolved by below ways -

- **Simulate the action of wearable** and generate out-put with the help of electronic boards [Same as wearable will generate]
- If you decide not to go for above solution as of now, Then you need to **follow inject methods** [Limitation - Those should be perfectly matching with results generated by wearables]